# How to reliably uninstall a Windows program with a script?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, e2e-testing, uninstallation

### Context

Our team develops a software program. It's an electron app which is distributed for Windows in an **MSI installer**. The installer is convenienly built by electron-builder, so we don't know its inner workings.

We run **end-to-end tests** of our program as part of an **automatic Gitlab CI pipeline**. To execute the jobs, we have configured a local Windows runner. For proper testing of the GUI, the `gitlab-runner` binary is started manually from a desktop environment, as opposed to the recommended service way.

Here's the basic workflow of the CI job:

- Get the MSI installer built by a previous job.
- Search the registry for the ProductCode of an already installed program version.
- Uninstall the program with `msiexec /uninstall {ProductCode}`.
- Check that the program's installation directory is empty.
- Install the new program version with `msiexec /i {PathToInstaller.msi}`.
- Run end-to-end tests that simulate user behavior.

### The problem

We're having regular stability issues on Windows, where jobs fail randomly and a developer has to remotely connect to the runner machine and fix things.

We have found the uninstaller to be very unreliable. Sometimes it fails to remove the program's folder, sometimes the registry values. In many cases it still returns success with no apparent errors. The installation gets corrupted so that it can only be fixed manually.

Sometimes we corrupt things ourselves, it is the testing process after all. We want a reliable non-manual way to just remove everything, leave no artifacts, and start from a clean slate.

### The question

How can a Windows program be uninstalled in a reliable way?

### Possible solutions

1. Windows Docker containers. They would be ideal, but, unfortunately, our app doesn't work in their limited environment.
2. There's also Windows Sandbox, which seems like a possible alternative to Docker containers. **Can it be automated?**
3. For consumer use, there's a lot of "Program Uninstallers", which track all installations and can reliability and completely remove programs. **Are there any CLI alternatives to them?**
4. Manually make scripts that delete all the possible things. This seems error-prone and impossible to maintain. And nobody in our team has knowledge on Windows (un)installers.

Answer (score 0):

Start by evaluating log files from the uninstall to see what is causing the uninstall failures. Your installation package may be built improperly or too fragile to handle all situations during uninstall. The Windows Installer is a very robust installation system when used correctly.